# unable to load image asset in Flutter error in pubspec file

Tags: dart, flutter, yaml, flutter-dependencies

i want to import image asset into my flutter project but unable to do so.

this is my pubspec.yaml file
i removed all the comments added by flutter

```
name: first_try
description: A new Flutter project.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
 
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter




  fonts:
    - family: Raleway
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Raleway-Black.ttf
        
    - family: Lato
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf #works till here
    -assets:
      -assets/
```

Error Given:

[first_try] flutter packages get
Running "flutter packages get" in first_try...                      0.4s
Error detected in pubspec.yaml:

## /properties/flutter/properties/assets: type: wanted [array] got -assets/

Please correct the pubspec.yaml file at B:\Flutter_Exercise\first_try\pubspec.yaml
exit code 1

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/50OOV.png <=folder structure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might have forgotten an whitespace. 
Try the following:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/
```

notice the whitespace after the `-`

Furthermore, i think, you've removed the `flutter` section while removeing the comments. AFAIK, that's important :)

see https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#specifying-assets for more information

Comment: can you plz recommend a plugin in vs code for yaml files?

Answer (score 0):

You should be use only one tab space before "fonts" and plus tab when use "-" all of below.

Answer (score 0):

image: AssetImage('images/dice1.png'))
flutter:
uses-material-design: true
asset:

- images/
  whats the problem cant load the pic

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you're following the Udemy flutter course. Edit the pubspec.yaml file like below:

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
     - assets/images/dice-1.png
     - assets/images/dice-2.png
     - assets/images/dice-3.png
     - assets/images/dice-4.png
     - assets/images/dice-5.png
     - assets/images/dice-6.png
```